# Changing background color on DIV - Swap color with tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the background color of three divs when they are clicked. I have managed to change the background color and content of the div when it is clicked but can't work out how to return the div to the original state?

It should function as three tabs along the top (one,two,three) with one by default green, when any of the others are clicked the defaut changes and the one that was clicked changes.  http://jsfiddle.net/0es6neph/

Tab One should be selected by default.

Am I going the right way about this or is it a messy solution to a straightforward problem ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentDiv = null;

function swapin(divName){
if(currentDiv != null){
document.getElementById(currentDiv).style.display = "none";

}
if(document.getElementById != 'contain'){
document.getElementById('1').style.display = "none";
}
currentDiv = divName;
document.getElementById(currentDiv).style.display = "block";
}
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('1').style.display = "block";
}

</script>

<style>
.tabs {
    background-color:#7D135A;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 90px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    }

 .contain {
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    border:2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #7D135A;
    }



</style>

<a href="javascript: swapin('1');" class="tabs">One</a>&nbsp;
<a href="javascript: swapin('2');" class="tabs" >Two</a>&nbsp;
<a href="javascript: swapin('3');" class="tabs">Three</a>&nbsp;

<div id="contain" class="contain">
<div id="1" style="display: none;">
One Content
</div>
<div id="2" style="display: none;">
Two Content
</div>
<div id="3" style="display: none;">
Three Content
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
$(".tabs").click(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#008000');
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should start by converting all remaining Vanilla to jQuery for readability reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really messy ... I detected some unnecessary routes in your code:

1) Use ids starting with a letter like #tab1 and never numbers alone.
2) No need to encapsulate this process in a function. This is a straightforward procedure that doesn't need to be addressed like a repetitive pattern.
3) Do not call the function inside the href attribute. Use onclick to run JS click instructions instead.

Use this approach instead: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/henser/0es6neph/5/)

```
$(function () {
    $(".tab").click(function () {
        var tab = $(this),
            dataTab = tab.attr('data-tab');
        tab.addClass('active').siblings('.tab').removeClass('active');
        $('#'+dataTab).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: edited the fiddle ... I believe it is working as intended now ... check it!

Comment: That is exactly how it should work, apart from tab 'one' is selected by default (green). It is much simpler way than I was doing it. Can I ask so I understand it, what was the difference between the first & second versions ? The first seemed to work fine too and be shorter ? Thanks !

Comment: what do you mean with the first and the second versions?

Comment: Exactly, just trying to get my head around why the second is better? They both seem to work great....

Comment: Edited answer with some of the reasons ... additional reasons would be ... you're not making unnecessary if statements in your code ... you're making use of jQuery (if it's being loaded to your website ... you better make use of it)

Comment: check updated answer ... I've added a class active to put the active tab green on window load also ... I think now you have the cleanest working approach.

Comment: Amazing thank you. I think this is the most elegent solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a class for changing the state of your links.

Add this in css

```
.active{
    background-color: #008800;
}
```

Change your click function to this

```
$(".tabs").click(function () {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

Check it out here in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49rx50fc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give those div a class for eg: `.bg` and then in you should change in jQuery the background color like `here`.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery as you have already load it.
And try not to mesh up your code.

```js
var openTab = null;

function swapin(newTab){
    if(openTab != null){
        openTab.css('background-color','#7D135A');
        $(openTab.data('tab-element')).css('display',"none");
    }
 
 newTab.css('background-color','#008000');
    $(newTab.data('tab-element')).css('display',"block");
 
 openTab = newTab;
}

$(function () {
    $(".tabs .tab").click(function () {
        swapin($(this));
    });
});
```

```css
.tabs .tab{
    background-color: #7D135A;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 90px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.contain {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #7D135A;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
    <a click="swapin()" class="tab" data-tab-element="#1">One</a>
    <a click="swapin()" class="tab" data-tab-element="#2">Two</a>
    <a click="swapin()" class="tab" data-tab-element="#3">Three</a>
</div>
<div id="contain" class="contain">
    <div id="1" style="display: none;">
        One Content
    </div>
    <div id="2" style="display: none;">
        Two Content
    </div>
    <div id="3" style="display: none;">
        Three Content
    </div>
</div>
```