# Change background color of div when they are selected?

Tags: menu, colors, background, selected

In this case **DIV's** are to act as category buttons and the users will be able to select multiple categories at one time, when they select a category, the background color will change for the user to know what categories are currently selected.

So, **DIV's** are transparent when not active, then when user press some of them, they turn some color, telling the visitors that they are currently active.

I'm sorry if I'm stupid in explaining, hoping for some help from you guys!

Comment: are you using any code? an example or what you have done already would help. otherwise were guessing

Comment: Have you tried something ? Is javascript permitted ?

Comment: I think you can refer to this link to solve your problem.......

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961933/changing-background-color-on-div-swap-color-with-tabs

Comment: @NoLiver92 - Well, I want to use jQuery, if that is what you mean? This is the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/599fd9be/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
 $('.cat').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('selected');
 });
});
```

```css
.cat {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #a3a3a3;
 margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 200px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cat1" class="cat">cat 1</div>
<div id="cat2" class="cat">cat 2</div>
<div id="cat3" class="cat">cat 3</div>
```

Comment: Yes, like this, except I want "selected" class to get removed if the user clicks it again.

Comment: then replace $(this).addClass('selected'); with $(this).toggleClass('selected');

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy for you! No need to use any javascript.

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
     label.category > input{
      visibility: hidden;
      position: absolute;
    }
    label.category > input + div{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:#999 solid 1px;
    margin-left:10px;
    }
    label.category > input:checked + div{
      background-color: #FCF;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="">
<label class="category">
          <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="item1"/>
          <div>
          Item 1
          </div>
        </label>
        <label class="category">
          <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="item2"/>
          <div>
          Item 2
          </div>
        </label>
        <label class="category">
          <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="item3"/>
          <div>
          Item 3
          </div>
        </label>
</form>
```